# Mysql exited with status 1 and restarted every 24 hours? How to debug?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

After upgrade, MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04 keeps crashing and is restarted every 24 hours according to the dmesg. I would expect to some reason for the failure in MySQL logs, but all are empty. Any ideas how to debug this?

```
[32973.265291] init: mysql main process (944) terminated with status 1
[32973.265369] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[32974.838809] type=1400 audit(1427596253.637:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" n
me="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5319 comm="apparmor_parser"
[119355.299897] init: mysql main process (5342) terminated with status 1
[119355.299975] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[119356.129273] type=1400 audit(1427682634.929:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
ame="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=14595 comm="apparmor_parser"
[205744.920406] init: mysql main process (14616) terminated with status 1
[205744.920472] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[205745.237559] type=1400 audit(1427769024.039:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
ame="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=23793 comm="apparmor_parser"
[292141.907015] init: mysql main process (23806) terminated with status 1
[292141.907071] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[292141.937585] type=1400 audit(1427855420.737:27): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
ame="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=523 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: Does the crashing coincide with anything run out of cron, such as a logrotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Plotnick, there was an entry in cron coinciding with the time of crash (4:30am - run dmesg -T to display absolute times). It was a database backup dump (mysqldump) which crashed the mysql service (huh...). The crash was caused by corrupted tables after server crash due to power failure.

To be honest I expected it to be a bit more resilient than this. I would expect mysqldump not to crash the whole service.... but maybe it is more complicated than I think.